# Android Studio 3.0 Error: unknown element <uses-permission> found

Tags: javascript, java, android, barcode-scanner, android-studio-3.0

So I'm trying to build some kinda scanner application that requires camera permission, I'm trying this at the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and then I got an error like this:

```
Error:(28) error: unknown element <uses-permission> found.
Error:(28) unknown element <uses-permission> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You have that `<uses-permission>` element in the wrong spot in your manifest. It belongs outside of the `<application>` tags.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much Sir! It works! but now I got a new problem which is after scanner did the scanning, it only shows the result. I can't click on the url. Can you help me?

Comment: That's a separate issue. You'll have to post a new question for that. Make sure to include a detailed description of the problem, and the relevant code and XML.

Comment: @MikeM. I see. Thank you again Sir, you help me a lot.